# How do I configure which disk becomes /dev/sda?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have a machine with an SSD and a HDD. After swapping the HDD for a newer model, I noticed that now upon reboots, my SSD is identified as `/dev/sdb` and my HDD as `/dev/sda`.

Since I prefer having my Linux installation on `/dev/sda` instead, how can I configure my system so that this device is always identified as `/dev/sda`?

Comment: Have a look a udev rules, this is probably what your distro is using to name the device at boot

Comment: Swapping the connectors on the MB?

Comment: You might consider using persistent block device naming.   If your machine has more than one disk controller, the order in which their corresponding device nodes are added is arbitrary. This may result in device names like /dev/sda and /dev/sdb switching around on each boot.  Persistent naming solves this issue.

Comment: @fpmurphy I mount my HDD via PARTLABEL, so I have a persistent method of addressing and mounting the devices. I just dislike that they randomly swap device identifiers.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I did that, but it is random. Sometimes they're in the order I want, sometimes not.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Yes, my distro uses udev, but I will be honest, I couldn't really make sense of the documentation

Comment: I don't think udev documentation is meant for us mortals.  But if you ran "assigning fixed drive letters via udev" through duckduckgo, you might get some understandable results.